# Margin of a Div Effects Another Non-Related Div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="footernote">
    <p>
       One statement ....
    </p>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Current Visitors: 11</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="copyright">copyright statement</a></p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: 18px;   
}

footer ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.copyright {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: small;
}

.footernote {
    text-align: center;
}
```

*Problem:*

1. **If i put margin-bottom value in `.footernote`, whatever inside `<footer>` changes its position due to the margin-bottom value i put in `.footernote`. footernote is not in `<footer>`, so they are both different elements. How come the set of `<footer>` gets effected by `.footernote`?**
2. **Same problem appears when i change margin-top of footer ul! Copyright statement gets effected, it pulls up or down based on margin-top i put in footer ul. `<p class="copyright">` is a separate element. Any idea why does this indirect effect occur?**

Comment: and...... The final effect should be? How should it look? What are you trying to achieve? It's a bit unclear from your question

Comment: Could you perhaps [post a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us the problem? I'm having trouble reproducing what you're talking about.

Comment: If by "changes its position" and "gets effected" you mean the elements are pushed down or pulled up, then thats supposed to happen... margin adds height to the box of the elements, and thus will push (or pull, if set to a negative value) all the contents below them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain without a test case, but this is almost certainly "collapsing margins" at work:

> Certain adjoining margins combine to form a single margin. Those
>   margins are said to “collapse.” Margins are adjoining if there are no
>   nonempty content, padding or border areas or clearance to separate
>   them.

The spec:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

Some easier reads:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing